# com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException in android

Tags: android, gson

*I am getting error : com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 3*


**My Code:**

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String[] placelist;
placelist = gson.fromJson(result, String[].class);
// Assign the String array as Country Spinner Control's items
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, placelist);
spinnerFood.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**I am getting output in result which is as below :**

```
[{"CityId":1,"CityName":"Vadodara"},{"CityId":2,"CityName":"ahmedabad"},{"CityId":3,"CityName":"Gandhinagar"},{"CityId":4,"CityName":"Bhavnagar"},{"CityId":15,"CityName":"Anantapur"},{"CityId":16,"CityName":"Srikakulam"},{"CityId":17,"CityName":"Rajahmundry"},{"CityId":18,"CityName":"Guntur"},{"CityId":29,"CityName":"Hyderabad"},{"CityId":30,"CityName":"Karimnagar"}]
```

Please help me to solve this problem. I have already added gson.jar file in configuration.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think: (Your JSON is not String array, It is Object Array)

```
public class City {
   private String cityId;
   private String cityName;

   // Getters, Setters
}
```

And parse by GSON

```
City[] placelist;
placelist = gson.fromJson(result, City[].class);
```

You can read more about Gson at: [Gson Example](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html)