# Unable to fetch Data from An API( Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $)

Tags: java, android

trying to fetch data from an API " http://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/top_rated?api_key=8496be0b2149805afa458ab8ec27560c ".
I have used Intent Service for this.

But Geeting an error " com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $"

Is their a problem with the Dataitem class?
I generated the code for same using "http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/"
Any help is really appreciated.

Dataitem.java

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class Dataitem implements Parcelable {

    private String posterPath;
    private double popularity;
    private int id;
    private String backdropPath;
    private double voteAverage;
    private String overview;
    private String firstAirDate;
    private String originCountry;
    private Integer genreIds;
    private String originalLanguage;
    private int voteCount;
    private String name;
    private String originalName;

    public String getPosterPath() {
        return posterPath;
    }

    public void setPosterPath(String posterPath) {
        this.posterPath = posterPath;
    }

    public double getPopularity() {
        return popularity;
    }

    public void setPopularity(double popularity) {
        this.popularity = popularity;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getBackdropPath() {
        return backdropPath;
    }

    public void setBackdropPath(String backdropPath) {
        this.backdropPath = backdropPath;
    }

    public double getVoteAverage() {
        return voteAverage;
    }

    public void setVoteAverage(double voteAverage) {
        this.voteAverage = voteAverage;
    }

    public String getOverview() {
        return overview;
    }

    public void setOverview(String overview) {
        this.overview = overview;
    }

    public String getFirstAirDate() {
        return firstAirDate;
    }

    public void setFirstAirDate(String firstAirDate) {
        this.firstAirDate = firstAirDate;
    }

    public String getOriginCountry() {
        return originCountry;
    }

    public void setOriginCountry(String originCountry) {
        this.originCountry = originCountry;
    }

    public Integer getGenreIds() {
        return genreIds;
    }

    public void setGenreIds(Integer genreIds) {
        this.genreIds = genreIds;
    }

    public String getOriginalLanguage() {
        return originalLanguage;
    }

    public void setOriginalLanguage(String originalLanguage) {
        this.originalLanguage = originalLanguage;
    }

    public int getVoteCount() {
        return voteCount;
    }

    public void setVoteCount(int voteCount) {
        this.voteCount = voteCount;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getOriginalName() {
        return originalName;
    }

    public void setOriginalName(String originalName) {
        this.originalName = originalName;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(this.posterPath);
        dest.writeDouble(this.popularity);
        dest.writeInt(this.id);
        dest.writeString(this.backdropPath);
        dest.writeDouble(this.voteAverage);
        dest.writeString(this.overview);
        dest.writeString(this.firstAirDate);
        dest.writeString(this.originCountry);
        dest.writeValue(this.genreIds);
        dest.writeString(this.originalLanguage);
        dest.writeInt(this.voteCount);
        dest.writeString(this.name);
        dest.writeString(this.originalName);
    }

    public Dataitem() {
    }

    protected Dataitem(Parcel in) {
        this.posterPath = in.readString();
        this.popularity = in.readDouble();
        this.id = in.readInt();
        this.backdropPath = in.readString();
        this.voteAverage = in.readDouble();
        this.overview = in.readString();
        this.firstAirDate = in.readString();
        this.originCountry = in.readString();
        this.genreIds = (Integer) in.readValue(Integer.class.getClassLoader());
        this.originalLanguage = in.readString();
        this.voteCount = in.readInt();
        this.name = in.readString();
        this.originalName = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Dataitem> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Dataitem>() {
        @Override
        public Dataitem createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Dataitem(source);
        }

        @Override
        public Dataitem[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Dataitem[size];
        }
    };
}
```

MyService.java

```
package com.example.sumeet.basicmoviestry2.services;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.sumeet.basicmoviestry2.model.Dataitem;
import com.example.sumeet.basicmoviestry2.utils.HttpHelper;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MyService extends IntentService {

    public static final String TAG = "MyService";
    public static final String MY_SERVICE_MESSAGE = "myServiceMessage";
    public static final String MY_SERVICE_PAYLOAD = "myServicePayload";

    public MyService() {
        super("MyService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Uri uri = intent.getData();
        Log.i(TAG, "onHandleIntent: " + uri.toString());

        String response;
        try {

            response = HttpHelper.downloadUrl(uri.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Dataitem[] dataItems = gson.fromJson(response, Dataitem[].class);

        Intent messageIntent = new Intent(MY_SERVICE_MESSAGE);
        messageIntent.putExtra(MY_SERVICE_PAYLOAD, dataItems);
        LocalBroadcastManager manager =
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        manager.sendBroadcast(messageIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "invoked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy");

    }

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.sumeet.basicmoviestry2;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.sumeet.basicmoviestry2.model.Dataitem;
import com.example.sumeet.basicmoviestry2.services.MyService;
import com.example.sumeet.basicmoviestry2.utils.NetworkHelper;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tvShow;
    Button btn_run;

    private static final String JSON_URL =
            "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/top_rated?api_key=8496be0b2149805afa458ab8ec27560c";

    private boolean network0k;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                .registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver,
                        new IntentFilter(MyService.MY_SERVICE_MESSAGE));

        tvShow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_home);
        btn_run = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_run);
        network0k = NetworkHelper.hasNetworkAccess(this);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "network= " + network0k, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public void runData(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(JSON_URL));
        startService(intent);

    }

    private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Dataitem[] dataItems = (Dataitem[]) intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(MyService.MY_SERVICE_PAYLOAD);

            for (Dataitem items : dataItems) {
                tvShow.append(items.getId() + "\n");


            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                .unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
    }
}
```

Networkhelper.java(To check Connectivity)

```
package com.example.sumeet.basicmoviestry2.utils;

/**
 * Created by Sumeet on 04-05-2017.
 */

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class NetworkHelper {

    public static boolean hasNetworkAccess(Context context) {

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        try {
            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            return activeNetwork != null &&
                    activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

HttpHelper.java(To read the data)

```
package com.example.sumeet.basicmoviestry2.utils;

/**
 * Created by Sumeet on 04-05-2017.
 */

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class HttpHelper {

    public static String downloadUrl(String address) throws IOException {

        InputStream is = null;
        try {

            URL url = new URL(address);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode != 200) {
                throw new IOException("Got response code " + responseCode);
            }
            is = conn.getInputStream();
            return readStream(is);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static String readStream(InputStream stream) throws IOException {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        BufferedOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            int length = 0;
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(byteArray);
            while ((length = stream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            out.flush();
            return byteArray.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.sumeet.basicmoviestry2.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn_run"
        android:onClick="runData"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21374603/com-google-gson-jsonsyntaxexception-java-lang-illegalstateexception-in-android

Comment: Are you sure to use the right url ?, in your MainActivity JSON_URL is different from what you mention in your question. Make sure about that

Comment: had updated incorrect API Link earlier, Apologies. Have made the correction now.

Comment: Can you please check now ?

Answer (score 0):

if you use `JSON` parsing using `Gson` then you have to make the first JSONObject in response like below

Dataitem.java

```
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Dataitem {

    @SerializedName("page")
    @Expose
    private Integer page;
    @SerializedName("results")
    @Expose
    private List<Result> results = null;
    @SerializedName("total_results")
    @Expose
    private Integer totalResults;
    @SerializedName("total_pages")
    @Expose
    private Integer totalPages;

    public Integer getPage() {
        return page;
    }

    public void setPage(Integer page) {
        this.page = page;
    }

    public List<Result> getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(List<Result> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }

    public Integer getTotalResults() {
        return totalResults;
    }

    public void setTotalResults(Integer totalResults) {
        this.totalResults = totalResults;
    }

    public Integer getTotalPages() {
        return totalPages;
    }

    public void setTotalPages(Integer totalPages) {
        this.totalPages = totalPages;
    }

    public class Result {

        @SerializedName("poster_path")
        @Expose
        private String posterPath;
        @SerializedName("popularity")
        @Expose
        private Double popularity;
        @SerializedName("id")
        @Expose
        private Integer id;
        @SerializedName("backdrop_path")
        @Expose
        private String backdropPath;
        @SerializedName("vote_average")
        @Expose
        private Double voteAverage;
        @SerializedName("overview")
        @Expose
        private String overview;
        @SerializedName("first_air_date")
        @Expose
        private String firstAirDate;
        @SerializedName("origin_country")
        @Expose
        private List<String> originCountry = null;
        @SerializedName("genre_ids")
        @Expose
        private List<Integer> genreIds = null;
        @SerializedName("original_language")
        @Expose
        private String originalLanguage;
        @SerializedName("vote_count")
        @Expose
        private Integer voteCount;
        @SerializedName("name")
        @Expose
        private String name;
        @SerializedName("original_name")
        @Expose
        private String originalName;

        public String getPosterPath() {
            return posterPath;
        }

        public void setPosterPath(String posterPath) {
            this.posterPath = posterPath;
        }

        public Double getPopularity() {
            return popularity;
        }

        public void setPopularity(Double popularity) {
            this.popularity = popularity;
        }

        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getBackdropPath() {
            return backdropPath;
        }

        public void setBackdropPath(String backdropPath) {
            this.backdropPath = backdropPath;
        }

        public Double getVoteAverage() {
            return voteAverage;
        }

        public void setVoteAverage(Double voteAverage) {
            this.voteAverage = voteAverage;
        }

        public String getOverview() {
            return overview;
        }

        public void setOverview(String overview) {
            this.overview = overview;
        }

        public String getFirstAirDate() {
            return firstAirDate;
        }

        public void setFirstAirDate(String firstAirDate) {
            this.firstAirDate = firstAirDate;
        }

        public List<String> getOriginCountry() {
            return originCountry;
        }

        public void setOriginCountry(List<String> originCountry) {
            this.originCountry = originCountry;
        }

        public List<Integer> getGenreIds() {
            return genreIds;
        }

        public void setGenreIds(List<Integer> genreIds) {
            this.genreIds = genreIds;
        }

        public String getOriginalLanguage() {
            return originalLanguage;
        }

        public void setOriginalLanguage(String originalLanguage) {
            this.originalLanguage = originalLanguage;
        }

        public Integer getVoteCount() {
            return voteCount;
        }

        public void setVoteCount(Integer voteCount) {
            this.voteCount = voteCount;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getOriginalName() {
            return originalName;
        }

        public void setOriginalName(String originalName) {
            this.originalName = originalName;
        }

    }
```

MyService.java

```
   package com.example.sumeet.basicmoviestry2.services;

    import android.app.IntentService;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.example.sumeet.basicmoviestry2.model.Dataitem;
    import com.example.sumeet.basicmoviestry2.utils.HttpHelper;
    import com.google.gson.Gson;

    import java.io.IOException;

    public class MyService extends IntentService {

        public static final String TAG = "MyService";
        public static final String MY_SERVICE_MESSAGE = "myServiceMessage";
        public static final String MY_SERVICE_PAYLOAD = "myServicePayload";

        public MyService() {
            super("MyService");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
            Uri uri = intent.getData();
            Log.i(TAG, "onHandleIntent: " + uri.toString());

            String response;
            try {

                response = HttpHelper.downloadUrl(uri.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Dataitem dataItems = gson.fromJson(response, Dataitem.class);
            String str = new Gson().toJson(dataItems);

            Intent messageIntent = new Intent(MY_SERVICE_MESSAGE);
            messageIntent.putExtra(MY_SERVICE_PAYLOAD, str);
            LocalBroadcastManager manager =
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            manager.sendBroadcast(messageIntent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "invoked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy");

        }

    }
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.sumeet.basicmoviestry2;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.sumeet.basicmoviestry2.model.Dataitem;
import com.example.sumeet.basicmoviestry2.services.MyService;
import com.example.sumeet.basicmoviestry2.utils.NetworkHelper;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tvShow;
    Button btn_run;

    private static final String JSON_URL =
            "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/top_rated?api_key=8496be0b2149805afa458ab8ec27560c";

    private boolean network0k;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                .registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver,
                        new IntentFilter(MyService.MY_SERVICE_MESSAGE));

        tvShow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_home);
        btn_run = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_run);
        network0k = NetworkHelper.hasNetworkAccess(this);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "network= " + network0k, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public void runData(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(JSON_URL));
        startService(intent);

    }

    private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String str = intent.getExtras().getString(MyService.MY_SERVICE_PAYLOAD);
       Dataitem dataItems =  new Gson().fromJson(str,Dataitem);

            for (Dataitem.Result items : dataItems.getResults()) {
                tvShow.append(items.getId() + "\n");


            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                .unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
    }
}
```

Networkhelper.java(To check Connectivity)

```
package com.example.sumeet.basicmoviestry2.utils;

/**
 * Created by Sumeet on 04-05-2017.
 */

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class NetworkHelper {

    public static boolean hasNetworkAccess(Context context) {

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        try {
            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            return activeNetwork != null &&
                    activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

HttpHelper.java(To read the data)

```
 package com.example.sumeet.basicmoviestry2.utils;

    /**
     * Created by Sumeet on 04-05-2017.
     */

    import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;

    public class HttpHelper {

        public static String downloadUrl(String address) throws IOException {

            InputStream is = null;
            try {

                URL url = new URL(address);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.connect();

                int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                if (responseCode != 200) {
                    throw new IOException("Got response code " + responseCode);
                }
                is = conn.getInputStream();
                return readStream(is);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (is != null) {
                    is.close();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        private static String readStream(InputStream stream) throws IOException {

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            BufferedOutputStream out = null;
            try {
                int length = 0;
                out = new BufferedOutputStream(byteArray);
                while ((length = stream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                out.flush();
                return byteArray.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            } finally {
                if (out != null) {
                    out.close();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: made the above corrections, but in the line "  messageIntent.putExtra(MY_SERVICE_PAYLOAD, dataItems);"  i am getting an error now as" cannot resolve the method putExtra()."

Comment: please check my last updated answer at the bottom of

Comment: please check last updated my answer and look at bottom of answer

Comment: and then you can access dataItems.get(0).getPosterPath();

Comment: The code mentioned after "//and get value time" that needs to be placed inside onreceive of BroadcastReceiver ?

Comment: in Myservice i made a change as asked for and now it looks like this   " Intent messageIntent = new Intent(MY_SERVICE_MESSAGE);
        String str;
        str = new Gson().toJson(Dataitem);
        messageIntent.putExtra(MY_SERVICE_PAYLOAD, str);" stil getting a error in line " str = new Gson().toJson(Dataitem);" under Dataitem saying"Expression Expected"

Comment: I see the older comments from you are removed now , have you edited all these files ?

Comment: the code, "
            String str = intent.getExtra().getString(MyService.MY_SERVICE_PAYLOAD);
            Dataitem dataItems =  new Gson().fromJson(str,Dataitem);" is where i am getting error now for getExtra() saying "can not resolve the method"

Comment: use" String str = intent.getExtras().getString(MyService.MY_SERVICE_PAYLOAD); "

Comment: please check above comments

Comment: unable to understand the comment "Use  String str = intent.getExtras().getString(MyService.MY_SERVICE_PAYLOAD); "  its the same code i mentioned is showing error

Comment: shall i share my code with github ? if that helps ?

Comment: Any thoughts on this?